# Cannot delete object from list

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an object

```
Ticket
-List<AssociatedUsers> Users

AssociatedUsers
-Ticket Ticket
```

My mapping looks like this:

```
// Ticket Map:
HasMany(t => t.Users)
                 .Inverse()
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();       

// AssociatedUsers Map:
References(u => u.Ticket).Cascade.SaveUpdate()
```

When I try to delete a assocateduser from the baseTicket list I get an error saying:

> deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)

I have tried some variations of Cascades but I cant figure it out and I would like to know why its not working instead of getting lucky by chance.

```
var user = FindAssociatedUserInTicket(userName);
user.AssertIsNotNull("No user found");
session.Delete(user);
```

I have tried:

```
ticket.RemoveUserFromList(userName); //List.Delete function for the found user
session.Save(ticket)
```

Comment: Can you show your code for deleting the associated user?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to cascade the Ticket?

```
// AssociatedUsers Map:
References(u => u.Ticket).Cascade.SaveUpdate()
```

Removing cascade and use your second approach:

```
Ticket.RemoveUserFromList(userName);
session.Save(ticket)
```

Comment: I want the cascades to work so I can save either the follower or the ticket and everything will be saved appropriately. If there is no way to do this then so be it but I would think there would.